# How to set user Role in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using ASP.net MVC.
So I want to set the user role when longing.

So this is my controller

```
public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {                
        var user = GetuserByname(model.UserName);
        if (user.ToList().Count == 1)
        {
            string dbPassword = user.First().UserPassword.ToString();
            string enterPassword = CreatePasswordHash(model.Password, user.First().Salt.ToString());

            if (dbPassword.ToString().Trim() == enterPassword.ToString().Trim())
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.First().tblUserRole.RoleName, model.RememberMe);
                Session["logged"] = user.First().Username;


                string roleName = user.First().tblUserRole.RoleName;
                Roles.AddUserToRole(model.UserName, roleName);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }                
    }            
    return View(model);
}
```

This is my webconfig file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>

    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ApplicationServices1" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
        <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
        <add name="SKGEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model1.csdl|res://*/Models.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=SKG;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    </connectionStrings>

    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="~/Login/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>

    <membership>
        <providers>
            <clear />
            <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="3" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
        </providers>
    </membership>

    <profile>
        <providers>
            <clear />
            <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
        </providers>
    </profile>

    <roleManager enabled="true">
        <providers>
            <clear />
            <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
            <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
        </providers>
    </roleManager>

</configuration>
```

But there is error  and it says...

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server

...I don't know how to fix it.

Also how can I set the...

```
 Roles.AddUserToRole(xxx, yyy);
```

...in my controller?

Thank you.

Comment: So, on a separate topic... just a word of advice, cleaning up your controller code to make it a little more readable will really help the next guy down the road. Here's a suggestion, take it with a grain of salt (no pun intended). It's just a suggestion that might help you... https://gist.github.com/ChaseFlorell/5218298

Comment: @Chase: that wasn't a pun in the first place.

Comment: @Dai read the OP's code `model.Password, user.First().Salt.ToString())`... ok ok, it's not really clear, and I'm definitely not funny...

Answer (score 3):

The error message says your database, a SQL server, is inaccessible.

Your providers (role, membership, profile) are set up to use the `ApplicationServices` connection string, which is:

```
data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;
Integrated Security=SSPI;
AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;
User Instance=true
```

...however your other connection string is

```
Data Source=(local);
Initial Catalog=SKG;
Integrated Security=True;
MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

...which is a different database server entirely.

Change your provider configuration to use the correct database server.

Comment: the question formatting was driving me crazy, so I was more focused on fixing it, and less focused on answering the question. +1 for getting to the root of the problem, unfortunately the coding style is going to leave the OP with many many more of the same types of issues down the road.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell What was wrong with the `web.config`? Just the formatting of it?

Comment: Just had a lot of irrelevant information in it. It's good practice to strip the irrelevant info from your code before posting it on SO.

Comment: To be fair to the OP, when you're a beginner isn't obvious what is relevant or not.

Comment: You're absolutely right, and in no way am I trying to insult or belittle. All I want to do is help. I deleted my original (sarcastic) comment, and added (hopefully) a helpful, more constructive one.